# The following html anchor tag for twitter

Tags: html

The following anchor tag

```
 <a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button external" data-text="check out ___ on MySite!" data-count="none" data-via="MySite">tweet</a>
```

I am wondering if special .js file needed? I mean, how does the browser know date-text, data-count fields? those are not standard, browser probably won't know that they mean.

But I seearch the whole file and couldn't find any reference to any .js file that relate to the twitter sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Tweet Button Docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button). You need to add the following line somewhere in your page for that special anchor to function:

```
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

Comment: Could this be the one?   $script("https://ws.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js",function() {
   stLight.options({publisher:'7e2916d2-9240-4a08-8a53-3227b0e1bc10'});
  });

Comment: @jasonwhite No, according to the docs I linked you need to have that particular line somewhere in your code.